# MYSQL select beep; - make mysql console beep when selected - or notified

Tags: mysql, beep

Rather a peculiar question.

Is there a possibility to "select beep" in mysql or any sql for that matter ? - I often run a few queries / updates / alter commands which takes quite some time and I wish when the query ends to be notified.

Is there anyway for the mysql client console to notify using audio / sound / beep ?

Before you all start crucifying me let's remember:

1. MySQL does beep on errors - so the possibility exists
2. MySQL or any console should be "friendly to the user", for example it includes the \G which allows to view the results in a more human readable format.

So why not beep ?

I know it is possible to achieve it using shell / bash command line or any scripting language.

Comment: I'm curious. I've never heard a mysql client console (or any other) beep before, even with errors. I've worked in many different OSs and never heard it before. Which client and OS are you using? Maybe it is something particular to your client/OS? AFAIK there is no such feature in MySql. Supposedly this would be a client feature, therefore my question. Cheers,

Comment: Dear @JorgeCampos! There is  `-no-beep` option to do not beep when errors occur. Of course it is disabled by default in many cases.

Comment: @majidhajibaba Thanks. Didn't even know it was an option.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple solution. However mysql use  `putchar('\a')` in its code to make a beep.

```
if (info_type == INFO_ERROR) {
  if (!opt_nobeep) putchar('\a'); /* This should make a bell */
  if (error) {
    if (sqlstate)
      (void)tee_fprintf(file, "ERROR %d (%s): ", error, sqlstate);
    else
      (void)tee_fprintf(file, "ERROR %d: ", error);
  } else
    tee_puts("ERROR: ", file);
}
```

If you compile mysql from the source you can use it everywhere in  **mysql-server/client/mysql.cc** specially at the end of for loop in `read_and_execute` function.